# SciPy optimize.curve gives two fit plots off one fit function

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am quite new to working with python, so I hope my question is not too dumb of a question.

I am currently trying different fits (linear, quadratic, cubic) for a set of data and in the end, I want to compare the different fits. But while doing so, after I tried a simple quadratic fit (f(x)=a*x^2+b), I also tried a quadratic polynomial fit (f(x)=a*x^2+b*x+c), but then the outcoming plot gave me two instead of one quadratic fits (with the linear fit in total 3). I am rather confused since when I first tried the simple quadratic fit, everything was fine (i.e. it only showed one fit). Only when I tried the quadratic polynomial fit, it started showing me two fits at once, and it still is, even when I try going back to only a simple quadratic fit.
I tried going back to the point when still everything was fine, but I can not reproduce the result I had and do not really know what I am doing differently now.

Best regards,

Earl_Earlson

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

dataset = pd.read_csv("data.dat", sep=" ",
                      names=["row number", "line center", "line center error",
                             "FWHM", "central intensity", "background", "integrated intensity"])

row_number = dataset["row number"].to_numpy()
line_center = dataset["line center"].to_numpy()


def lin_fit(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

params_lin, params_covariance_lin = optimize.curve_fit(lin_fit, row_number, line_center,
                                               p0=[-0.04, 1553])

print(params_lin)

def quad_fit(x, a, b):
    return a*x*x + b

params_quad, params_covariance_quad = optimize.curve_fit(quad_fit, row_number, line_center,
                                                         p0=[-2.08594942e-06, 1.55156043e+03])

#print(params_quad)

#def cub_fit() 


plt.plot(row_number, line_center, "go", markersize=1)
plt.plot(row_number, lin_fit(row_number, params_lin[0], params_lin[1]))
plt.plot(row_number, quad_fit(row_number, params_quad[0], params_quad[1]))

plt.show()
```

[There are 3 fitplots for only two fit functions and I do not know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBEB8.png)

Comment: Looks like you have 2 fit plots for your 2 fit functions, and one plot of a "line center" in your data. Could you clarify what you mean by seeing 3 fit plots? 

You call plt.plot() 3 times, so its expected that you would see 3 plots on your graph.

Comment: the added link shows the total plot. in there there are 3 fits and one plot of the raw data (just the dots).
yes i call plt.plot 3 times, but the first one is just to plot the data itself. the second one is the linear fit and the third one should show one quadratic plot, but shows two.

Comment: but I am starting to think that it is no extra fit, but rather the actual fit doing something weird at the end of the row_number interval. I mean it looks like it is doing the proper fit throughout the interval but in der end going back in a straight line to one point, and then go to another point in a straight line.

Comment: Yes, sorry I got distracted with another problem, but that's my feeling as well given the color of the plot. There's nothing obvious that I can see, but have you considered restarting your kernel and trying again? Or just clearing the plot? Maybe that extra line is a residual from a previous expriment you were running?

Comment: Hi there, sorry, I gave up last night and was pretty busy today.
I tried restarting the kernel and also clearing the plot. I also tried the paramters the scipy.optimize thingy gave me to create an own function with it, but it still gives these weird straight lines.

Comment: But please do not worry too much, I was just wondering if there is something obvious I am doing wrong. If that is not the case, I will just try and figure it out with my professor tomorrow or so.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the data set I was using did show various values for the same x value, but in quite a weird order. So I ended up fixing the order of the data and now the plots look fine.